# Add multiple ID's to container - Classie.js

Tags: javascript

I am using  [classie.js](https://github.com/desandro/classie). In the code that interacts with classie.js I want to add multiple id's to `container`.
Here is my code:

```
var docElem = window.document.documentElement,
                        scrollVal,
                        isRevealed, 
                        noscroll, 
                        isAnimating,
                        container = document.getElementById( 'container-2' ), 
                        trigger = container.querySelector( 'button.trigger' );
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: You can't add more than one Id to an HTML tag. The `id` attribute is an abbreviation for "Identifier," meaning that it identifies one, and only one, HTML tag in the document. Can you add some information about why you need multiple Ids?

Comment: actually i have created multiple container like "container-1", "container-2" ........."container-5" and now  i need to add all those container id to a javascript code to get a effects on all those containers